# ColdFusion regex to properly format an ipv6 address

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Although there are examples of this on SO, many of them deal with removing leading zeros or combining "0:0:" sequences into "::".  Most of the examples I've seen are for other languages.

Here's my function for compressing/formatting an ipv6 address:

```
<cffunction name="formatIPv6" returntype="string" output="yes" access="public" hint="returns a compressed ipv6 address">
    <cfargument name="vcIPv6" type="string" required="yes" hint="IPv6 address">

    <!--- inside reReplace removes leading zeros, outside reReplace removes repeating ":" and "0:" --->
    <cfreturn reReplace(reReplace(LCase(arguments.vcIPv6), "(:|^)(0{0,3})([1-9a-f]*)", "\1\3", "all"), "(^|:)[0|:]+:", "::", "all")>
</cffunction>
```

Running the function with sample ipv6 addresses will return the expected results:

```
formatIPv6(vcIPv6 = "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1") = ::1 (expected value = ::1)
formatIPv6(vcIPv6 = "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001") = ::1 (expected value = ::1)
formatIPv6(vcIPv6 = "1000:0:0:0:8:800:000c:417a") = 1000::8:800:c:417a (expected value = 1000::8:800:c:417a)
formatIPv6(vcIPv6 = "1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A") = 1080::8:800:200c:417a (expected value = 1080::8:800:200c:417a)
formatIPv6(vcIPv6 = "2001:db8:a0b:12f0:0:0:0:1") = 2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1 (expected value = 2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1)
formatIPv6(vcIPv6 = "fe80:0:0:0:204:61ff:fe9d:f156") = fe80::204:61ff:fe9d:f156 (expected value = fe80::204:61ff:fe9d:f156)
```

My question is can the two reReplace() functions can be replaced with a single reReplace()?

If there are better ways to do this I'm open to suggestions.